# How to find value of x?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

[image]

Find the value of x.

Trail: Let consider the point between B and C is D. So $\angle ADB =120^\circ$ and $\angle DAB =15^\circ$. I believe that $\angle DAC =30^\circ$. But I am not sure. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you believe that $\angle DAC = 30^\circ$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $h$ be the height from A to BC,

$$\frac{ h\cot45 - h\cot60}{h\cot x + h\cot60} = \frac12 $$
$$\cot x = 2\cot 45 -3 \cot 60=2-\sqrt3$$
$$ x = 75$$

Answer (score 0):

Apply the Sine Rule to $\Delta ADB$ and $\Delta ABC$ to find two expressions for $AB$. That lets you relate $\sin x$ to $\sin(x+45)$.   Then solve for $\tan x$.

Comment: I try to solve it but I'm stuck. please help see my answer

Answer (score 0):

So from $\triangle ADB$ using sine rule, we get 
$$\frac{\sin 15 }{1}=\frac{\sin 120 }{AB}=\frac{\sin 45 }{AD}$$
Similarly from $\triangle ABC$ using sine rule, we get 
$$\frac{\sin (135-x) }{3}=\frac{\sin x }{AB}=\frac{\sin 45 }{AC}$$

So equating $AB$ from this two equations we get
$$\frac{\sin (135-x) }{\sin x }=\frac{3\sin 15 }{\sin 120}$$

Then I'm stuck.

Comment: Do you know $\sin(x-y)=\sin x\cos y-\cos x\sin y$?

Comment: @Empy2 yes. how can I handle $#sin 15$?

Comment: $\sin15=\sin(45-30)$

Comment: @RDE Were you able to finish the problem with Empy2's hint?

Answer (score 0):

One way or another (there are multiple straightforward though slightly tedious ways to do this), show that $AC = \sqrt 6.$

For example, drop a perpendicular from $A$ to $BC$; let the intersection with $BC$ be $H$. Then $\angle BAH=45^\circ$, $\angle DAH=60^\circ,$ and if the length of $AH$ is $h$ then
$$1 = h(\tan(45^\circ)-\tan(60^\circ)) = \frac{3 - \sqrt3}3 h.$$
Hence $h = \frac12(3 + \sqrt3).$ But the length of $CH$ is
$3-h = \frac12(3 - \sqrt3),$ and
$(AC)^2 = h^2 + (3-h)^2 = 6.$

Then there are at least two quick ways to solve the problem.

One way is to observe that $\sqrt 6$ is the geometric mean of $CD=2$
and $BC=3.$ Therefore triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DAC$ are similar
with $\angle DAC = \angle ABC,$ and now you have two angles of $\triangle DAC$
and the third angle is easy to find.

Another way is to use the Law of Sines:
$$
\frac{\sin(60^\circ)}{\sqrt6} = \frac{\sin(\angle DAC)}{2}.
$$
You can solve for $\sin(\angle DAC),$ and then (as it happens in this question)
it is easy to see what $\angle DAC$ must be.